# Obstacles in job hunting for US citizens in non-US nations

Tags: job-search, job, international

I am curious to know the kinds of obstacles a US citizen would come across when trying to find work in academia outside the US and/or those that a non-US-citizen faces when trying to get an academic job inside the US.

It would seem that, logistically, it would be easier on the department to hire a citizen over a non-citizen. Is there any advice applicants can follow that would greater their chances?  Do you have to be extraordinary for a department to hire you over an equally qualified citizen?

Comment: If there's an *equally qualified citizen*, it doesn't matter how extraordinary you are, because that equally qualified citizen is just as extraordinary as you, and the government absolutely wants him to be employed.

Answer (score 7):

There a multiple levels on which this problem operates. This is especially true for places saturated with immigrants. (For instance, USA with Indians/Chinese)

- **Getting the Job**

  This problem itself has a million subdivisions. Firstly, it is fairly difficult for immigrants (who studied in that country) to get jobs without exhibiting something really outstanding. The problem is not so bad for sectors such as computer science and electrical engineering wherein professionals are required by the dozen. The problem, however, is really bad in areas such as Theoretical Physics or Chemistry (or basic sciences). With limited vacancies and a million outstanding candidates, it is really difficult to crack that "top job".
- **Working in Sensitive Sectors**

  I don't even want to get started on sectors like Aerospace. More often than not, graduates from the top universities in USA and Europe have returned to their homelands because all companies stress on citizenship. For EU, it is fairly difficult for a Non-EU resident to get a job in the first place, add to that defense and secrecy and you have a useless degree. In USA, it's even better, if you graduate with a PhD in Aerospace Control Systems from say, Stanford, you are still worthless for US companies because they don't ask just for citizenship anymore but also [Top Secret (or Lower) Security Clearance](https://owa.jhuapl.edu/psp/cg89prod_cg/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_CE.GBL?Page=HRS_CE_HM_PRE&Action=A&SiteId=1)! That's at least 10 years for a foreign citizen.
- **Immigration and Visa**

  Getting a job is one part, getting the necessary immigration documents cleared is another. I mentioned about Aerospace engineering being a potential problem as far as jobs are concerned. But thats not all! USA has published a [list](http://www.bu.edu/isso/forms/tal.pdf) called the technology alert list which requires screening of candidates before granting a visa.

  The immigration laws in the Europe aren't very friendly for Non-European to begin with but as far as I know, they don't maintain a strict segregation between "things non-citizens can't do" and "things they can". However, [rising](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/switzerland/8839006/Swiss-far-right-party-on-course-for-record-breaking-election-win.html) far-right politics, things don't seem to get any better in the future.

Comment: Switzerland is not Europe. What I want to say: I don't see rising far-right politics here.

Comment: [Italy](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2010/mar/30/italy-elections-far-right-berlusconi)
[Germany](http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/0,1518,815242,00.html)
[Greece](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/08/01/greece-far-right_n_915174.html)
[Europe](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2011/nov/06/far-right-rise-europe-report)
[Europe-Old](http://internationalviewpoint.org/spip.php?article1931).

Comment: I've followed one of the references and I didn't think it was a strong one. But this is getting far too OT.

Thus, I change my statement to "I don't see rising far-right politics in my local neighborhood" ;-)

Answer (score 6):

> Do you have to be extraordinary for a department to hire you over an equally qualified citizen?

That really depends on the search criteria. If the criteria specifically calls for international experience—and many jobs around the world now do exactly that—you might not be disadvantaged at all, and in some cases even have the upper hand.

That said, it *is* true that hiring a citizen is generally easier than hiring a non-citizen, and in the EU, it's easier to hire a non-citizen who lives in the EU than a non-citizen who lives outside the EU. The result will be a lot more bureaucracy. Whether or not the hiring unit wants to go through the extra trouble will make a lot of the difference, and it's not something you have much control over. (The same principle applies in the US for non-citizens!)

Answer (score 2):

In the US, if you're employed by a university or a government research lab, then you're exempt from the H1B visa cap. Thus the visa is not usually a problem.

Comment: I've never heard of universities being unwilling to sponsor H1B visas for tenure-track faculty (in my limited experience), but I have heard of some that will not do so for postdocs as a matter of policy and will insist on say a J1-visa instead. The J1 comes with a 2-year home residency requirement for people from certain countries, which might make it less desirable.